# Swap container elements order using CSS only

Tags: html, css

here is the challenge I'm trying to figure out. I need to swap A - B and E - F divs in reverse order using css, but C - D leave as it is.

Here is the code I'm using [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alex_sharapov/9duj4gny/11/)

```
<style>
.column div {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}
</style>

<div class="column">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</div>
```

[Image shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTAsR.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: `flexbox` + `flex-order` will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

As other's have mentioned already, you could try leveraging the CSS property [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items) inside a container with `display: flex`. By default elements are rendered in the order they appear in the document but you can change the ordering through that property.

### Demonstration

```css
.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column > div {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
}

.column > div:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}

.column > div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</div>
```

### Additional resources

You can always check [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for more explanation on the CSS flexbox.